# OutofMemory Exception happening in my lockscreen in android

Tags: android, heap-memory, lockscreen

I have created a custom lockscreen for my ICS android phone(It is not an application, I directly changes default lockscreen of android). It is using more bitmap images and i am also showing some animation with these images. I am using more than 50 images in my unlockscreen. When i am unlocking and locking the screen continuously observed that the heap memory goes on increasing in some extend and the phone get restarted. In the logs it shows outofmemory exception.

I have surfed through net and recycled the bitmap when it is not used and also scaled the images in the powers of 2. But nothing is going in my way.

Comment: Your android heap size is more than 16 MB and its create prblm and this question Asked many time out of memory Exception in stackoverflow....

Comment: @Samir: As mentioned in the question We have already checked some links regarding this issue but none of them are working.